# Google Maps v2 - Android Studio - OnLocationChanged not being called

Tags: android, google-maps, location

First of all, I´ve been searching for an answer for this the whole evening. I have read many of the questions -probably all- asking why OnloCationChanged is not called... nothing helped me.

I have a Fragment that displays a map. I can add markers to it and it also shows the current location of the user correctly. Everything seems to be ok but, I want to zoom in the user´s location and that´s why I need the method "OnLocationChanged" to be called.

Also, locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider) returns always null.

I have tested this in a real device.

Here is my configuration, I hope somebody can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

**Fragment Class**

```
public class MapMainFragment extends BaseFragment implements LocationListener{

private SupportMapFragment fragment;
private GoogleMap map;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private static final long MIN_TIME = 500;
private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 0;
String provider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // LOCATION
    locationManager = (LocationManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabledGPS = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    boolean enabledWiFi = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    // Check if enabled and if not send user to the GSP settings
    if (!enabledGPS && !enabledWiFi) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Define the criteria how to select the location provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Selected Provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_tab_b_second_screen, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    map = fragment.getMap();
    // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    // Add Marker
    final LatLng TEST_MARKER = new LatLng(50.34927, 6.26887);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(TEST_MARKER)
            .title("Title")
            .snippet("Sheeps: 4,137,400")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.e("onLocationChanged", "called");
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Disabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**BaseFragment class**

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
public AppMainTabActivity mActivity;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mActivity       =   (AppMainTabActivity) this.getActivity();
}

public boolean onBackPressed(){
    return false;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

}
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your onlocation change it runs but the you remove the updates and it doesn't run any more

Comment out this line in onlocationchanged

locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

And your getbestprovider method use true instead of false

Comment: Thanks @JRowan , I have made those changes you suggest but it didn't make any difference. The log message at the beginning of the onLocationChanged method is never printed.

Comment: As it is the only answer so far, I will accept it as valid although making those changes didn't fix the problem at the time. 
Today, I just tried again and... shazam! is working... Thanks @JRowan for trying.